# SSIS Configuration error: Cannot retrieve configuration table schema

Tags: sql, configuration, ssis

I'm trying to add a simple configuration to a SSIS package, of type SQL Server, so stored in a table. At the end of the wizard, when it goes to try and write a new row to the nominated table to store the configuration it fails with the error:

TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
Could not complete wizard actions.
Cannot retrieve configuration table schema. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Wizards)

I can't seem to resolve this. The configuration connection has full permissions on the table, and it sees it and can read from it as it reports there is no current data for the filter I provide. It just wont write to it. A Google search of the error message above in quotes returns literally no hits! Any suggestions?

Glenn

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a mismatch between the table structure that existed on my machine and the table structure that is used by a SQL Server Configuration. Ensuring the table matched the default SSIS Config schema below fixed the error.

[ConfigurationFilter] nvarchar NOT NULL,
[PackagePath] nvarchar NOT NULL,
[ConfiguredValueType] nvarchar NOT NULL,
[ConfiguredValue] nvarchar null

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs it, you have to verify if the packagePath column in your table has the correct string value, and it must match with the property that you want to configure.